# Recreate lifehacker ajax article page refresh, right menu is always visible, url & article changes

Tags: javascript, ajax

On [lifehacker.com](http://lifehacker.com/) when a user clicks a article on the right menu sidebar, the article & the page url changes, but the #rightcontainer always stays visible and , you never see it blink on the change of the page url, and when the article is ajaxed in (this is easy),

**How would you change the page URL with a DIV staying visible on the page the whole time.**

How is this possible? Javascript of some sort? (I think its freezing the browser then doing something, getting the data ready? )

I always thought you couldn't change the page url with javascript because of security issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for State Handling :)

It used to be done by adding # at the end of the URL, but now HTML5's State Handling features allow us to change the URL completely (ofc, within our domain)

The answer you need is located here:

https://github.com/browserstate/History.js/

Answer (score 0):

Each url can include the same source as right container it won't refresh/blink as in browser cache.

> *you couldn't change the page url with javascript because of security
>   issues*

A link can be followed via JavaScript if you require, its not regarded as bad practice (afaik).  But there is no **need** to use javascript it could just be normal anchor/href.

Comment: Hi, but including the same source will still reload the entire page, you would still see it blink as it would still need to be rendered from cache to screen with the rest of the site, this site is using something different.

Comment: @JustAnil, Hi, thats not true try it.